# Shifting Rows in Matrix by Variable Amounts

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, time-series

I have a time series dataframe (Pandas). The columns are timesteps and I would like to shift each row a variable amount while maintaining the column order.

A sample of my data:
[image]

I have a dataset full of shifts for every index in the dataframe. Here is a sample of the dataset full of shifts needed for every index.

[image]

What would be the easiest way to shift each row the given variable amount, while maintaining positioning with relation to the columns?

Comment: Can you post some sample data as text, with the expected outcome also as text?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, creating an example since I have no data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(5, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'),index=[1,2,3,4,5])
print(df)

    A   B   C   D
1  27  78  89  75
2  24  36  33  97
3  27  45  85  31
4  82  48  93  31
5  19  42   2  85

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(6,1)),columns=['to_shift'])
print(df1)

   to_shift
0        37
1        96
2        23
3        48
4         8
5        17
```

Subtract `df` from the ``series in `df1` without shuffling column order

```
df_new=df.sub(df1.to_shift,axis=0).dropna(how='all')
print(df_new)

     A     B     C     D
1 -69.0 -18.0  -7.0 -21.0
2   1.0  13.0  10.0  74.0
3 -21.0  -3.0  37.0 -17.0
4  74.0  40.0  85.0  23.0
5   2.0  25.0 -15.0  68.0
```